# Can a double jump move backwards in Checkers/Draughts?

Tags: checkers

In Checkers, can a non-kinged piece jump backwards as the second jump in a double jump?

Comment: In several computer versions of the game (as well as how i learned to play in real life), you are allowed to jump backwards if and only if the piece is a king at the time of jumping.  In particular, if the piece begins as a non-king, makes a jump and is promoted, it may make a second jump backwards if eligible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This depends on the variation you're playing. A lot of variations allow capturing backwards with regular pieces (called men). The English variation is probably the most common that doesn't allow backwards capturing. By the international rules, capturing backwards is allowed (and mandatory if it results in the largest capture group).

There's an [extensive list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts#National_and_regional_variants) on Wikipedia, describing which variations allow backwards capturing by men, and which don't.

Answer (score 3):

We grew up playing that the only time a non-king piece could go backwards is if the play was a multi-piece knockout and the the first opponet piece jumped was not a backward jump. So, if it was a three jump knockout, the first jump had to be forward but the 2nd or 3rd could be backwards

Comment: This answer does not add anything that was not already in another answer.

Comment: @MikeR There are a couple of things wrong with your comment. First is this answer talks about allowing backwards jumps as a house rule when the accepted answer mentions official rules for a backwards jump. Second you should never assume who voted on a post. I have made no votes on this question at all and did not provide the downvote for this answer that was someone else. Third you should never instruct (or even recommend) someone on what to do with their votes.

Comment: @JoeW.  My apologies, comment retracted.  My concern was that a new user had been instantly downvoted when it didn't seem warranted, and that it might drive the new user away from the site.  I should have learned from past experiences not to get involved in things like this.  I attempted to remove my vote from this answer as well but am not allowed to.

Comment: Welcome to the site, user15052! I like the idea behind this variation, and it's different from the ones covered in my answer. Thanks!